# How to improve readability of a specification document containing lots of tables?

Tags: documentation

We maintain a technical project whose specifications are in a document of few hundred pages. It's a text document (Word), not a Wiki or a Web-based stuff.

The document contains **lots of tables** with values (strings, numerical, parameter names) . Some tables are **huge** (hundreds of data), other are quite **small**.

I'm looking for **good practices/best approaches** to get **readable** and **comfy** documents, especially **data tables**, avoiding hard to distinguish rows from content around, and also not some overly colored stuff making it hard to focus on. (As a side note, the specification contains also pseudo-code and code samples, formatted and highlighted with styles in a way like does SE markdown engine.)

I got this article : [Web Typography: Designing Tables to be Read, Not Looked At](https://alistapart.com/article/web-typography-tables/). It's aimed at Web design, It might be good for such documents.

Are there **guidelines** to write a easy-to-read technical specification? I understand it might be a subjective question... Some people likes colorful documents, others sober ones.

Comment: A vague question about "easy-to-read technical specification" in general is way-too-broad for the Q&A format for this site, and if you are asking for links or books: questions for 3rd party resources are off-topic here, please have a look into the [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But to your specific question about tabular documents, I think the linked article in your question can be applied to your case immediately, I could not see anything at a first glance which restricts it to Web design.

Comment: @Doc Brown, thanks. The question is specific to tables. (By the way I may have exaggerated by saying "hundreds" of datas, I wasn't meaning hundreds of _rows_).

Answer (score 2):

Large, highly-detailed, fiddly stuff is usually relegated to Appendixes, linked to be a hyperlink (for the online crowd) and/or a Page number (for the hard-copyists) in the main document.

That way, the reader can have both "open" at the same time, regardless of their reading medium of choice.

Read up on the [HyperLink](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/864f8577-eb2a-4e55-8c90-40631748ef53) and [PageRef](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/bbda448f-7233-4aaa-b061-55ca4664c4d7) **Field Codes** in Word.

Comment: Appendixes are a double-edged sword: they are fine to swap out things like statistics from the main part of a document, in case that main part can be understood without the appendix. But in case the "detailed stuff" is essential for the spec, they require the reader to switch back-and-forth between two different positions in the document (and yes, I read you idea of having "both" parts of the doc open at the same time). So I am missing here a clear warning in this answer to use appendixes with care, for not making the readability worse.

Comment: It's very hard to not turn a specification basically to a trashcan where you put stuff you won't read next, cause it stinks.